# How to transfer the large date from client to server?

Tags: c#, wcf

I am transferring the data from client to server using the following code at the client.

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath + dsBlockImages.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageName"].ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
eventLog1.WriteEntry(buffer.Length.ToString());
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    proxy.GetAllModuleDocumentsForServerSyncUp(buffer, dsBlockImages.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ImageName"].ToString(), fileindication);
}
```

In server I have written the following code in WCF service

```
if (!File.Exists(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filetargetpath) + FileName))
{
    FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(filetargetpath) + FileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
    writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    writeStream.Close();
}
```

This is working for small file if i send the large files it is giving bad request.
I have specified the  size limits in web.config also but it is giving same exception

```
<binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISyncUpService" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647"/>
    <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
    </security>
</binding>
```

Is there any other way we need to solve bad request problem.

Comment: Please pay attention to formatting the code samples to a readable state.

Answer (score 1):

1. Replace transferMode with Streamed
2. Return Stream from server instead of byte array
   You can find examples [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166763/WCF-Streaming-Upload-Download-Files-Over-HTTP) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33825/WCF-TCP-based-File-Server)